# Python cProfile : Can't get attribute 'myclass' on <module 'cProfile' from 'path_to_cProfile.py'

Tags: python, profiling, pickle, attributeerror, cprofile

When I try to run `python -m cProfile -o output.prof main.py` in the commandline I get the following error :

`Can't get attribute 'myclass' on <module 'cProfile' from 'path_to_cProfile.py'`

And it says that it is related to a line in code where I use pickle to load an object of class 'myclass'  `data = pickle.load(myfile)`

However, when I use directly in the main.py :

```
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
main()
pr.disable()
pr.dump_stats("stats.prof")
```

it seems to work normally.

Any idea ?

Thanks